# Crystal report (runtime 13.0.2) not release OBDC connection to MySql sever

Tags: mysql, asp.net, crystal-reports

Using crystal report for .NET runtime 13.0.2 with MySQL server. report is designed with odbc connection. when export the report to pdf the connection is not release to MySQL server. search the net, found some suggestions about closing the report document will release the connection, but whatever I try don't seem to work. went as far as going through each table and disposing the object and closing connections on the main and subreports.

```
foreach (Table table in _reportDocument.Database.Tables)
                            {                                    
                                table.Dispose();
                            }

                            // Now loop through all the sections and its objects to do the same for the subreports
                            //
                            foreach (Section section in _reportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections)
                            {
                                // In each section we need to loop through all the reporting objects
                                foreach (ReportObject reportObject in section.ReportObjects)
                                {
                                    if (reportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                                    {
                                        var subReport = (SubreportObject)reportObject;
                                        ReportDocument subDocument = subReport.OpenSubreport(subReport.SubreportName);

                                        foreach (Table table in subDocument.Database.Tables)
                                        {
                                            table.Dispose();
                                        }

                                        subDocument.Database.Dispose();
                                        subDocument.Close();
                                        subDocument.Dispose();                                           
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            _reportDocument.Database.Dispose();
                            _reportDocument.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
                            _reportDocument.Close();
                            _reportDocument.Dispose();
                            _reportDocument = null;
```

here's what we are running: MySQL 5.6.20, MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver and asp.net 4.0 and crystal report 13.0.12 64 bit, windows server 2008 R2 64 bit but the system DSN is 64 bit DSN.

is it the issue with ODBC driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

digging more into the crystal report support fourm. it turns out that it's a bug that they introduced into crystal report. see details discussion here: 
http://scn.sap.com/thread/3664672

hope anybody else having the same issue with crystal report will stop pulling their hair (for now).

switching back to 13 SP 10 fix the issue!! please stay away from SP12.